# orderBy phpunit test

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have a phpunit test which is used to test the ordering of films, i need to test that the query i have below returns and orders the status of a film by online but im unsure on what i do to insert that the online results are displayed first.

**query**

```
Film::select('films.*')
    ->when($filters->input('status'), function ($query, $status) {
            $query->where('status', $status);
    })
    ->orderBy('films.updated_at', 'desc')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

**test**
This below wont work but its a rough idea.

```
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function order_by_online_status()
    {
        $film = factory(Film::class)->create([
            'status' => FilmStatus::OFFLINE
        ]);

         $film2 = factory(Film::class)->create([
            'status' => FilmStatus::ONLINE
        ]);

        $response = $this->json('GET', '/films');

        $this->assertEquals(
            $film, $film2);
}
```

how would i `assertEquals` that online is listed first.

Comment: You can pick first item and asset equals on that

Comment: Can you show me a code example please ?

Answer (score 1):

I would assert the response of the request and since this is a request I would also do an assertion of the response status code. I would do it in the following manner:

```
<?php
public function test_index_default_order_by_online_status()
{
    $film1 = factory(Film::class)->create([
        'status' => FilmStatus::OFFLINE
    ]);

     $film2 = factory(Film::class)->create([
        'status' => FilmStatus::ONLINE
    ]);

    $this
        ->json('GET', '/films')
        ->assertOk()    // assert the response have status code 200
        ->assertJson([  // assert the order
            $film2,     // film2 goes first since you ordered by created_at desc
            $film1
        ]);
}
```

You have to be mindful about the json that you are asserting here as you might have returned the result in a different format using transformer. So it would be better if your transform the result into the same format that you used on controller before the assertion. For example:

```
<?php

public function test_index_default_order_by_online_status()
{
    $film1 = factory(Film::class)->create([
        'status' => FilmStatus::OFFLINE
    ]);

     $film2 = factory(Film::class)->create([
        'status' => FilmStatus::ONLINE
    ]);

    // parse the result
    $result = $this->getExpectedResult([$film2, $film1]);

    $this
        ->json('GET', '/films')
        ->assertOk() // assert the response
        ->assertJson($result);
}

private function getExpectedResult($data) {
    return fractal($data, new FilmTransformer())->toArray();
}
```

The other thing that you have to take note is the `updated_at` attribute which you are sorting against. Although `$film1` and `$film2` are created in order, however due to the speed that the test are running, the `updated_at` might not be consistent which will cause the test to fail. Therefore I would advise adjusting the time of the creation before your test.

I'm gonna use `setTestNow()` method from `Carbon` in order for us to manipulate the time during the test.

```
<?php
public function test_index_default_order_by_online_status()
{
    // set $film1 creation time
    Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::create(2019, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0));

    $film1 = factory(Film::class)->create([
        'status' => FilmStatus::OFFLINE
    ]);

    // set $film2 creation time
    Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::create(2019, 1, 1, 11, 59, 59));

    $film2 = factory(Film::class)->create([
        'status' => FilmStatus::ONLINE
    ]);

    // reset the time
    Carbon::setTestNow();

    $result = $this->getExpectedResult([$film2, $film1]);

    $this
        ->json('GET', '/films')
        ->assertOk() // assert the response
        ->assertJson($result);
}
```

By doing so you can ensure that the `updated_at` attribute will be different.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a few records, if you know the expected result, create a json variable and compare that with the result.

```
    $jsonFilms = "[{
            "id": "0",
            "film": "name",
            "status": "Offline",
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "film": "name1",
            "status": "Offline",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "film": "name2",
            "status": "Offline",
        }]";

$this->assergEquals($response, $jsonFilms);
```